# How to create a custom cart quantity number that updates with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, magento, magento2

I'm setting up a new Magento2 webshop and I want to make a custom cart count number that updates it's number with Ajax like the standard minicart count number.

I already got some code that displays the cart quantity but it doesn't update with Ajax. (Page needs to be refreshed before the user sees a change)
The PHP below shows the cart quantity count:

```
$helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
echo $helper->getSummaryCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the issue with only update cart then by implementing below code you can update cart.

```
require(['Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function (customerData) {
            var sections = ['cart'];
            customerData.invalidate(sections);
            customerData.reload(sections, true);
        });
```

Main thing to do here is to reload custom data.